# Unable to import matlab.engine in python

Tags: import

import matlab.engine

In my case, with MATLAB R2014a, I got the following error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matlab'

and this path "matlabroot\extern\engines\python" is not present

Comment: The error message looks unmistakable enough. Where does `matlabroot\extern\engines\python` get into the picture?

Comment: Before this post I was tried to find solution on internet there is one solution that ' python setup.py install' into "matlabroot\extern\engines\python" but this path is not present in my laptop. Now what will I do?

Comment: (First thing to do would be to find out a) the value of MATLABROOT: I take that to be a variable, one place to look would be "the" (process-) *environment* (If you squint at MathWorks' installation instruction, you will find only that part of the installation instructions in Italics.) . b) how to install the *MATLAB® engine*) - once in that directory with a working python, it *should* be simple as `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 1):

"matlabroot" is not part of the path name.  It needs to be replaced with the name of the MATLAB root directory.  Typically that's, "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\20???" 
 Where ??? is replaced by your MATLAB version number.

So, open the command prompt with administrative privileges.
cd "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\2014a\extern\engines\python"
python setup.py install

If you don't have admin privileges, you can use this command to name alternative directories for setup.py to use:
python setup.py build --build-base="builddir" install --prefix="installdir"

Good luck!